# Количество хитов пользователя в 1С-Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс, сессия, seo

Здравствуйте!
Здача такая: Нужно получить количество хитов (переходов по страницам) юзера или гостя. Пытлася использовать `CHit::GetList()`, передавал туда массив с id сесии, но стандартная `bitrix_sessid()` возвращает сессию в md5, а в документации в примере id сессии простое число.
Как в итоге правильно получить количество хитов юзера?

Answer (score 0):

Есть переменые в которых хранятся идентификаторы пользователя,я так подозреваю вам нужно в фильтре указать вот это $_SESSION["SESS_GUEST_ID"]. Вот ссылка где описаны все внутринние переменые https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/statistic/variables.php